# Make left div height tight without affecting other div in parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Was unsure on how to name this one, so apologies if it's confusing. Basically, I'm creating a tabbed module where the `.right` div is always the same height.

The `.left` div houses the links/tabs, but I want this div's height not to match the `.right` ones.

For example, in the below approach, I want the div with the text "Content" to be auto (match the text height).

**Approach:**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left,
.right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right {
  background: red;  
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="left">Content</div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="left">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

So something like this:

[image]

I've achieved the above by just doing `<div class="left">Content<br>Content 2</div>` for demo purposes.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `left` as a `flex` container, and add two children to it. Then, set first child's `height` property to 100%. Like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left,
.right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="row1">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        Content2
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this won't work for me as I cannot alter the markup to have `.row-` div's under the `.left` one. For example, this is how my markup would look like with your approach: https://jsfiddle.net/pw0dj4a5/